# IE10+ Select element options list not interpreted as a child of parent element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, html-select

In IE 10 and 11, a rendered options list of a `<select>` element doesn't seem to be considered a child of its parent element, at least as far as transitions are concerned.

Assume we have a `<div>` that is styled using CSS transitions such that on hover, it slides right 100px and off hover, it slides back.

If we add a `<select>` element inside the `<div>`, it still slides right on hover. However, if I click the `<select>` and hover inside the list of `<option>'s`, the `<div>` slides back into its original position as if I've moved the cursor outside the `<div>`, rather than staying transitioned. The only explanation for this I can come up with is that somehow, IE is interpreting the select list or the options themselves as being outside of the parent element.

This snippet shows how it plays out. Try it in Chrome/FF/Safari vs IE10+.

```css
.test {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 1s;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.test:hover {
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    Move me
    <select>
        <option>Test</option>
        <option>Test</option>
        <option>Test</option>
        <option>Test</option>
        <option>Test</option>
        <option>Test</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I've tried this same example in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari and I get the expected behavior - the `<div>` stays transitioned even when my cursor is on the `<select>` list. I only see it slide back in IE and I'm thinking it's a browser bug.

If this is somehow intentional by the developers of IE, is there some way to style the elements such that my transition still works?

UPDATE 12/10/14 - At the time of writing, the only two select replacement libraries I found that implement the options list such that it is a child element of the select's parent are [Selecter](https://github.com/Formstone/Selecter) and [Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen). Ended up going with Selecter.

Comment: In Chrome there's also some weird behavior: if you open the select while it's on the left and move the mouse out of it, the div will move but the options will remain in the same place. Moving the mouse over them won't make the div slide left, so it looks like Chrome doesn't consider them a "child" of the parent div either (or it does, but only in some cases).

Comment: That is weird. Fortunately, I don't need to worry about showing the options during the transition. It's not ideal behavior, but if it's consistent across browsers, then I can live with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Internet Explorer we actually implement the dropdown list as a *separate window*. I am able to see the issue in IE 11 though, and can certainly see how that is frustrating. The good news is it appears we have already addressed this, and shipped the code on http://remote.modern.ie (run from Mac OS X, or Windows).

Expect the change in behavior to land in a future build of IE.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Any idea how I might handle this on IE10? I assume patches like these are only for the most recent version.

Comment: @thewildpendulum Your best bet (even if we patch IE 10) would be to use a third-party solution, such as [jQuery UI's Select Menu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/). This can get you up and running *today*.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. Very helpful, though. Thanks, @Jonathon!

Comment: I assume this fix never made it into IE11? At least in version 11.0.14393.0 I am still seeing this behavior