# Fixing :hover pseudo class in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-11

IE is having the problem that the `:hover` pseudo class doesn't work as intended when there is an open `select` element. As soon as the dropdown is open and the mouse is moved over the options, all parent tags loose the `:hover` pseudo class.

This is due to the fact that the open dropdown is implemented as a new window ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27259937/572644))

I am trying to fix this with Javascript by using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on the parent element, however, unfortunately, `mouseleave` is also raised when the user moves the mouse over the open dropdown.

My attempt so far:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var select = document.getElementById("select");

//$('#select').select2();

container.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  container.classList.add("hover");
});

container.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  container.classList.remove("hover");
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

#container:hover,
#container.hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<select id="select">
<option>Some option 1</option>
<option>Some option 2</option>
<option>Some option 3</option>
</select>
<p>
some long text text text text text<br>
some long text text text text text<br>
some long text text text text text<br>
some long text text text text text<br>
some long text text text text text<br>
some long text text text text text<br>
some long text text text text text<br>
some long text text text text text<br>
some long text text text text text<br>
some long text text text text text<br>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, in IE11, the mouseleave event is triggered when your mouse goes over the select (even if it's contained by the parent div that you're listening on). Try checking the event's "relatedTarget" property to see if you're "leaving" the div for a descendant, or if you're actually leaving the div:

```
container.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget && !container.contains(e.relatedTarget)) {
    container.classList.remove("hover");
  }
});
```

Basically, **only remove the "hover" class if the element we're moving to 1) exists and 2) is not a descendant of our container.**

- For the lazy: https://jsfiddle.net/q1p5gLLh/6/
- About "relatedTarget": https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_relatedtarget.asp
- Bonus: "relatedTarget" is compatible with all major browsers.

EDIT: the reason we check "e.relatedTarget" before seeing if it's contained by the container (no pun intended) is because it's possible "relatedTarget" is null. In fact, "relatedTarget" is *consistently* null when you mouse over the select dropdown. I'd be interested in knowing why this is the case, versus triggering "mouseleave" upon leaving the div for the HTML body, where you do get an element for "relatedTarget".

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. I guess `relatedTarget` is `null` for the same reason this problem exists: The dropdown is implemented in its own window in IE